# Using an apple script to copy then do a terminal command

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

This is my first time creating an apple script.

I am trying to create a script on my mac so that it duplicates a folder called '1-Client Template', I then want Terminal to ask me what I would like to rename it to and then finally run a few terminal commands.

Here's the terminal commands I want it to run

```
cd ~/Documents/Clients/TEMPLATE/Projects/Website/5-Website && git init && git add . && git config --global user.email 'name@email.com' && git config --global user.name 'Full Name' && git commit -m 'initial commit, added all website files' && git status
```

I know the ask for input part is certainly wrong but I can't figure this bit out. This is my script so far...

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        set ~/documents/Clients/1-Client\ Template to ~/documents/Clients/ask for input
    else
        return
    end if
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "cd ~/Documents/Clients/TEMPLATE/Projects/Website/5-Website && git init && git add . && git config --global user.email 'name@email.com' && git config --global user.name 'Full Name' && git commit -m 'initial commit, added all website files' && git status
"
    activate
end tell
```

I made this code looking at other online examples but I'm not quite getting it.

I'm getting the following error

```
Expected expression but found unknown token.
```

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script` does not need a tell block, and does not even need terminal to be running, because it calls the shell directly.

If you need to ask the user for input (i.e. the new filename), and you're using AppleScript, there are ways to prompt for a string, such as `(text returned of (display dialog "foo" default answer "bar"))`, or if you need to select a folder, you might use `(quoted form of (POSIX path of (choose folder)))`, similarly for files you might use `(quoted form of (POSIX path of (choose file)))` both of which will give you a shell-friendly string path derived from the Mac GUI.

To do the actual renaming, you'll either have to use the Finder (which is harder than you might think, because it has a completely different way of referring to files) *or* a carefully constructed `do shell script` call using (e.g.) `mv`, which is probably better, as you will be doing it with POSIX paths, rather than Finder file references, and it will be easy to do the git stuff, or whatever afterwards.

Comment: Using mv would be ok, my aim is to create a shortcut to run the command. I've read and re-read what you wrote bit I'm still not getting it. Do you have an example? I've spent all night and morning on what I thought was a simple task and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain briefly how you intend to invoke the script - script menu? droplet? scriptable application? folder action? Also, what will you typically be doing when you run it? The workflow would help choose the 'best' approach.